# Define pandoc md to tex conversion rules?

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, tex

Is it possible to define how headings are converted from Markdown to LaTeX?

I would like to convert

```
# Heading 1
```

to

```
\chapter{Heading 1}
```

and

```
## Heading 2
```

to

```
\section{Heading 2}
```

and so on.

Comment: I think you'll have to write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) that increments the heading integer by one...

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [option now](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#reader-options):

```
pandoc --base-header-level=2
```

---

Old answer:

I think you'll have to write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) that increments the heading integer by one, something along the lines of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

main :: IO ()
main = toJSONFilter inchead
  where inchead (Header n attr xs) = Header (n+1) attr xs
        inchead x = x
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now (Oct. 2023), the option `--base-header-level` has been deprecated; and the accepted solution by @mb21 does not convert level 1 headings to `\chapter{}` anymore.

It has been replaced by the new option `--shift-heading-level-by` (https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#reader-options) . However, level-1 headings (`#`) are mapped to `\section{}` and using `--shift-heading-level-by=-1` causes them be replaced by plain paragraphs, since they are moved "up" to level-0, which is invalid.
This is caused by the fact that Pandoc considers `\section{}` to be the highest level of headings for a document by default, making `\chapter{}` unattainable in this way.

**Instead**, one should use the option `--top-level-division` (https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options-affecting-specific-writers). It accepts the values `section` (default), `chapter`, and `part`.

Therefore, using

```
pandoc --top-level-division=part
```

maps level-1 headings to `\chapter{}` and level-2 headings to `\section{}`, as desired.

Note: `--top-level-division=part` can still be combined with `--shift-heading-level-by=-1` for example, to map level-2 headings to `\chapter{}` instead (and map level-1 headings to paragraphs again).